# Restore MSSQL database on remote machine from backup file via C# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, restore

I have a mssql database on remote machine and backup file for this database. I want to create a method (c#) for restoring of database from backup. I will execute my method on my local machine. Can somebody help me to create such method for restoring remote database?

Comment: Where do you need to restore the DB?Showing us some code of what you've tried would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the this:

```
    public  void RestoreDatabase(string fileName)
    {
        try 
        {           
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
            {
                string sql = "RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabase FROM DISK = N''" + fileName;
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                _command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw;
        }
    }
```

You call it this way :

```
    RestoreDatabase(@"\\remotemachine\...\YourFile.bak");
```

NB: Put an actual path for where the file is located